# Live geolocation web app android

Tags: android, node.js, web

I want to create a node.js web app that when you select a user from a list shows you its location in real time. The user has to get the Android Application activated.

I know how to do the android application, but the part of the web application I don't know how to raise it.

The only thing that occurred to me is to keep the location in a database table and a web socket get the position of the user.

An example of what i want is Runtastic on live.

Thanks.

Comment: Even though not in node.js this tutorial might help you in your design - https://www.typesafe.com/activator/template/reactive-maps-java

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the way to do, with socket.IO, it is for Node.js.
For each Android application connected to the server I assign a Room (ID), and I save in a table of DDBB.
When a User of the web wants to view a user, gets the ID of the Room from the DDBB and Join to the socket room.

[Rooms with sockets.IO](http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/)

[Socket.IO implementation Android](http://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/)